# Using $match twice through mongo aggregation pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I 'm facing an issue while trying to get some results from a mongoDB aggregation pipeline.
Here's what my DB look like:

```
var dbSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    identity: Number,
    parametres: {
        style: {
            fuel: [styleSchema],
            gasoline: [styleSchema],        
            },
        },
```

And here's what the styleSchema looks like:

```
var styleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   date: Date,
   value: Number,
   type: String,
});
```

I'm trying to extract ALL the objects in 'fuel' and 'gasoline' which are of some kind of 'type'.

I've tried to group both in a unique array with concatArray and then match the 'type' I want by:

```
db.aggregate([

  {$match:
      {'identity':3,
   }},
  {$project: {all: {$concatArrays: ['$parametres.style.fuel','$parametres.style.gasoline']} }},

  {$match: {'$all.type': 'example'}},
```

Before trying to match the second time, I've got a unique array ('all') and I try to match some things on it, but nothing works (I've tried 'all.type' also)...

I've probably misunderstood the way I have to use the 'match' query as I am a beginner, so thanks for your time and your answers,

Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.aggregate([
        {
            $match:{identity:3}
        },
       {
            $project: {all: {$concatArrays: ['$parametres.style.fuel','$parametres.style.gasoline']} }
       },
       {$unwind: "$all"},
       {$match: {"all.type": 'example'}},
       {$group : {_id: null, all:{$push:"$all"}}}
    ])
```

Probably you are trying to do something like this.
In aggregate operation, the `$` is used in right side of `:` to mention field name and in left side to mention operator. 
So when you are using "$all.type" in left-hand side `MongoDB` is treating it as an operator which is not available in the Mongodb operator list.

Another thing is that when you do any query over an `array`. Mongodb sends back the full array if atleast one of the element matches the condition. So we need to use `$unwind` operator to deconstruct the array before doing any query.